# How to excute a Java program on a Unix server?

Tags: java, unix

I have to create a Unix shell script to execute Java code which takes a input file and creates an output file. This is how I do it on Windows:

```
C:\Work\MCDExcelParserJE\bin>java -classpath .\;.\jxl.jar medicaid.Test PROCESS
```

How can I run this on Unix?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that you need to use `colon(:`) instead of `semi-colon(;)` in your classapth:

```
java -classpath .\;.\jxl.jar medicaid.Test PROCESS
```

should be updated to

```
java -classpath ./:./jxl.jar medicaid.Test PROCESS
```

Make sure you have jdk/bin directory is added to path in order to run the java commands.

Comment: Now I m getting this :The java class could not be loaded. java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: medicaid/Test (Unsupported major.minor version 49.0)

Comment: The version of the class files is higher than what the JVM supports.  Try recompiling them in the same machine/installation or using `javac` switches to target a lower JVM version.

Comment: It seems that you have compiled the java classes on a higher version of jdk and your unix machine is running on a lower version of jre. If you have .java classes on unix machine then first do the compilation using javac command. And then run using java command

Comment: thanx alot all. i was using lower version of JVM